# adding a dialogue box to java and retrieve the html file

Tags: java, html, url

Ok so this is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Html {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a URL");
String address = "http://";

URL chula = new URL(address+name);
URLConnection yc = chula.openConnection();
//BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt");
while (in.hasNext()) {
String inputLine = in.nextLine();
output.println(inputLine);


String line = in.next();
if (line.contains("href=\"http://")) {
            int from = line.indexOf("\"");
            int to = line.lastIndexOf("\"");
            System.out.println(line.substring(from + 1, to));



        }
       in.close();
         output.close();
         }

           }}
```

What i want to do is "The user to type in a URL into the dialogue box. The URL we have to use is "http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~adrian/CS5015refs.html". Then i want the program to save the HTML contents of that URL into the file specified but not all of the HTML code. Just the links in the webpage. basically the "a href" parts

Does that make more sense?At the moment it wont even save anything it comes up error when i type in the URl into the dialogue box

Comment: how did you add a dialogue box? Please share.

Comment: I have a second file with the dialogue box but without the new file so it doesn not save. but the dialogue box works and allows the user to enter a URL. i basically want to combine both codes together as one. I'll edit the question and add the second file above now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you want is this:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a URL");
String address = "http://";

URL chula = new URL(address+name);
URLConnection yc = chula.openConnection();
//BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc
  //      .getInputStream()));
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt");
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String inputLine = in.nextLine();
    output.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
output.close();
```

Edit:
I don't understand what you want to do.

Do you want to save the urls that the used type into the 'newFile.txt' file?

If It is, you don't need the URLConnection or the Scanner, you should open the file and append the address+name:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true))
);
out.println (address+name);
out.close;
```

Edit 2: Ok, this is what you need:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())).useDelimiter("\n");

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new File("allLinks.txt"));
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String inputLine = in.nextLine();

        String line = in.next();
        if (line.contains("href")) {
            int from = line.indexOf("href=");

            int to = line.substring(from).indexOf(">");

            String link = line.substring(from+6, to-1);

            System.out.println(link);
            output.println(link);
        }

    }
   in.close();
   output.close();
```

First, you need to say to Scanner which is the delimiter to use (end of line), by default it uses blankspace.

You have to use a File for PrintWriter.

And you have to search for 'href' and the next '>' after 'href' to get the clean link.

Comment: Thank You,
I dont quite exactly know how to validate the name value.
cant i just add the String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a URL");
String address = "http://";
i cant just add this to my other file no? its not that simple?

Comment: Sorry I'm just very new to Java and we've been given this question to look at

Comment: For validating the url you should validate if the return value begins with 'www.' or similar (www2 p.e.), a valid name without not valid characters (www.ggo??le.com <- not valid the '?' chars) and that ends with a valid domain (.com, .org, .es, .uk, etc...)

Comment: Thanks I'll work on that. We might not need that yet because we are just starting off. Do you have any idea how to just story the links int the URL given. it stores the entire HTML code. Do you know how to just story the links int he file? If not it's ok You've helped me a lot already

Comment: OKay sorry. It works but it saves all the HTML. do you know how to just save the links within the URL/webpage given

Comment: Ok, if you only want the hyperlinks of every website, you must to check for every line readed with the scanner if it contains a '<a href' text, and recover a substring from the first position of '<a href' until you find the next '<a/>' closing tag.

Comment: yeah ok thanks ill find out how to do that. I just edited the question. it may be easier for you to read now

Comment: 1 last question if you're not sick of me already. It doesnt seem to be saving the file. do you know the reason behind this?

Comment: It saves the file, are you launching the app from Eclipse? Search in the root directory of the project.

Comment: Im doing all this in Dr.Java and it doesnt seem to be saving the file anywhere

Comment: I have tested in Eclipse and it generates the file. Modify the example and set the absolute path to the file (for example: c:\temp-java\result.txt).